# Programmatically add ImageView and text to GridView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I'm display a list of items that has this same format (and I don't know how many of them):

```
Icon  SomeText  SomeText  SomeText
Icon  SomeText  SomeText  SomeText
...
```

I am using a GridView to display this so the list is scrollable.

I believe an ArrayAdapter would help me fill in the text fields.

But about the Icon fields, because they are .gif URLs, I am thinking about downloading the images first then put each one in an ImageView but I haven't figured out how do I programmatically do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are libraries for that, most notably [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) by guys from square, and [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) used in samples from Google.

Spend two minutes with google.com and found a tutorial for your https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-adapter-use-for-listview-gridview-etc/

But then, you are using GIF files, so I guess you should us

[Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)

as it supports GIF format.

So replace picasso used in tutorial with Ion and you should have what you want.

Comment: Small note: Glide also supports Gifs since version [3.0](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki#whats-new-in-30).